# Day Name for a calculated date

Tags: javascript, java

Hi Im new to Java and Im trying to workout the Day Name for a calculated date.
Im using Esko Automation Engine to run my Java

If I create a JavaScript script based on the actual date it works out using the following function:

```
function f () {
    var date = new Date().toString().split(' ')[0];
    return date;
}

f ();
```

But when I try and replace new Date() with another calculated date it fails.
The calculated date displays like this: 05/02/19 10:00am and is stripped out of a xml file.
This is named ScotlandDeliveryDate

```
function f () {
    var date = ScotlandDeliveryDate ().toString().split(' ')[0];
    return date;
}

f ();
```

Result:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: <eval>:4:25 Missing space after numeric literal
var date = 05/02/19 10:00am().toString().split(' ')[0];
^ in <eval> at line number 4 at column number 25
```

does anyone have any ideas please.

Comment: Can I know what is the purpose of the braces after ScotlandDeliveryDate? I think that ScotlandDeliveryDate is a variable which is having the date as the value. try removing that and writing var date = ScotlandDeliveryDate.toString().split(' ')[0];

Comment: What is `ScotlandDeliveryDate`? A `Date`? A function?

Comment: If I can count, column 25 would be where the `am` is or the `0` immediately preceding it. Is this correct?

Comment: What is `ScotlandDeliveryDate`? Is it a class? an object? Maybe you're missing `new` before it? Or there should be braces after `ScotlandDeliveryDate`

Comment: I am confused. Are you asking for Java code or JavaScript code? What *exactly* is your question?

Comment: ScotlandDeliveryDate is a smartname that Ive created that strips out a date from a supplied xml file. This then can be used in the javascript by inserting the smartname. (https://docs.esko.com/docs/en-us/automationengine/18/userguide/home.html#en-us/common/ae/concept/co_ae_SN_Script_Create.html) Ive tried removing the () but still errors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about "Esko". But in the example that you give above, you are trying to use one SmartName (`ScotlandDeliveryDate`) inside the definition of another SmartName.  At the link below, they seem to indicate that this is done by enclosing the SmartName in brackets.

https://docs.esko.com/docs/en-us/automationengine/18/userguide/home.html#en-us/common/ae/concept/co_ae_SN_Script_Exa.html

So I *think* your code needs to look like this:

```
function f () {
   return '[ScotlandDeliveryDate]'.split(' ')[0];
}
f ();
```

However, from your error message, it looks like `[ScotlandDeliveryDate]` will return `05/02/19 10:00am`;  If that's the case, then splitting that value on spaces and then grabbing the first value still won't get you the day name.

To do that, you'll need something like this:

```
function f () {
   var monthDayYear = '[ScotlandDeliveryDate]'.split(' ')[0];
   var dateTimeStamp = Date.parse(monthDayYear);
   var dateObject = new Date(dateTimeStamp);
   return new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {weekday:'long'}).format(dateObject);
}
f ();
```

Or, without the Intl object:

```
function f () {
   var dayNames = [
      'Sunday',
      'Monday',
      'Tuesday',
      'Wednesday',
      'Thursday',
      'Friday',
      'Saturday'
   ];
   var monthDayYear = '[ScotlandDeliveryDate]'.split(' ')[0];
   var dateTimeStamp = Date.parse(monthDayYear);
   var dateObject = new Date(dateTimeStamp);
   var dayNumber = dateObject.getDay();
   return dayNames[dayNumber];
}
f ();
```

Comment: If I run your first example I get the result 05/02/19 but the second function fails: Result: javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "Intl" is not defined in <eval> at line number 5

Comment: The `Intl` package is one of the standard, built-in Javascript objects for date conversion/manipulation that you probably don't have available to you in the "Esko" environment.  That just means that you'll have to do the conversion manually.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat

Comment: So on the `dateObject` value (above), you would call `dateObject.getDay()`.  That will return a 0-6 ordinal corresponding to a day of the week.

Comment: You create a reference array like so: ```var dayNames = [
 'Sunday',
  'Monday',
  'Tuesday',
  'Wednesday',
  'Thursday',
  'Friday',
  'Saturday'
];```

Comment: And then you can easily convert that day number to a formal name.

Comment: Do you mean like this:     function f () {
    var monthDayYear = '<<ScotlandDeliveryDate/>>'.split(' ')[0];
    var dateTimeStamp = Date.parse(monthDayYear);
    var dateObject = dateObject.getDay();
    var dayNames = [ 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday' ];
   var ScotdayName = dayNames[dateObject];
   return ScotdayName;
}
f ();

Comment: Apparently, I need to write out every line of every possible solution - so I've amended the answer above to explicitly show how it would be done without the `Intl` object.

Comment: Thanks Adam for writing it this out. And yes I have no idea what Im doing when it comes to java Script. by the way it works... Thanks again.